# WCF - static variables in a clustered environment

Tags: wcf, singleton

I want to try to set up some WCF services on a production environment with two or more clustered and load balanced web servers. Can anybody please answer the following questions?

1. In Clustered server environment, how can I use Singleton object and static variables?
2. EF Caching provider (see http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers-c0b88f32 ): can it be used in a clustered environment?